# Angular Universal homepage deployed on Vercel doesn't render server side

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, vercel

I deployed an Angular Universal website on Vercel, all routes are rendered in SSR mode except my HomeComponent. When I serve on localhost with `ng serve:ssr` command all pages are Server Side rendered.

My site is: [Site](https://ignaziosammarco.vercel.app/). My Github is: [GitHub](https://github.com/netsamma/sito-igna). Please some help!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I solved. I migrate my project to Angular 15 and installed Angular Universal 15. And all gone fine